# Linear function scoring in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a set of documents each with a content field and a date field. I'm trying to manipulate the score in a way that will boost newer documents.

I've found the linear decay score function but I'm having trouble understanding how it actually works.

```
"function_score": {
  "functions": [
    {
      "linear": {
        "date": {
          "scale": "30d",
          "offset": "7d",
          "decay": 0.5
        }
      }
    }
  ] 
}
```

For the above configuration, from what I understand, documents that are newer than 7 days will not have their scores manipulated, documents that are older than that will get a decrease of their score by 0.5 in intervals of 30 days, is that correct?

**Important Note: I'm using ES 1.7.4, newer ES versions have different definitions for the scale property**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"scale": "30d" => defines the rate of decay

"offset": "7d" => a distance greater that the defined offset results in decay
"decay": 0.5 => decay rate for documents which are (offset+-(n*scale)) days

> For the above configuration, from what I understand, documents that
>   are newer than 7 days will not have their scores manipulated

Not just newer but older as well i.e. within a distance of `offset` from current Date

Linear decay, computed as:

[image: Linear decay function]

where again the parameter s is computed to assure that the score takes the value decay at distance scale from origin+-offset

[image]

In contrast to the normal and exponential decay, ***`linear decay` actually sets the score to 0 if the field value exceeds twice the user given scale value.***

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)